# Cross table highlighting variable combinations

Tags: r

I'd like to make a data frame containing a table of proportions, and in this table I'd like to highlight certain combinations of the two variables. I'd like to highlight in yellow the cells with values for:

> blue and low
>   high and green
>   red and high

Current code:

```
df <- data.frame(op=c("high","medium","low","high","high","medium","low","high","medium"),fr=c("blue","red","green","green","red","blue","red","green","red"))
mytable <- table(df$op,df$fr)
df2 <- prop.table(mytable)
```

Comment: *Highlight in yellow the cells*... I think you are confusing R with excel..

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridExtra/vignettes/tableGrob.html). Close to the end of the page, there's a solution for colored highlighting of cells. Looks like `gridExtra`'s got your back. Although Excel would probably be more appropriate for this.